# Strange memory error dealloc/release

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I've been experiencing a weird error in my Objective-C program for iPhone. Here's what happens:

- I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.
- Fine, the zombies kick in and the log tells me it's about a CFNumber that gets a release, but is already deallocated. Still no tough cookie.
- I keep debugging until I hit a block with two NSNumbers. There are no CFNumbers in my code, so I reckon it's these lines.
- I try retaining them, with no success, even filling them with nil, overwriting them with new values, etc. Still nothing.
- I comment the lines out. Now the log keeps bugging about the same CFNumber, but now is being sent a "doubleValue" (instead of "release") while it's already deallocated. There is no "doubleValue" in my code.

What's going on here? Are the zombies messing with my code? I'm on a dead end here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Reinder

Comment: Guess something else autoreleased and that memory is being occupied by something else which comes up in your log.

Comment: I'm unable to help with most of the problem, but CFNumbers and NSNumbers are toll-free bridged, so they're exactly the same thing, to the point where they can't be distinguished at the machine level. A pointer to one is also a pointer to the other. So you're right to investigate NSNumber instances.

Comment: Have you run the Analyzer? Any warnings? If you have and it looks good, next step is to profile with Instruments using leaks.

Comment: Okay folsk, worked it out. Apparently I was just overwriting a property (which was retained), with a non-retained variable. Hence, the "already deallocated" errors. So, that said, I analyzed the code, fixed all the bad releases, dropped the bad habit, learned a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, not much we can do without code.

Here are some general principles to keep note of, and will make your life easier.

You refers to the current class.

- if you need to use it for a long period of time, retain it.
- if you don't need it at the end of a function, don't keep it (alloc, then release at the end) if you did not retain it, do not release it.
- if you did not alloc it, do not release it.
- if you are returning an object you allocated, and thus will lose control of it, autorelease (pretty much what it was designed for). This is in line with principle 3 and 4, as it means the calling class will need to make the decision to retain or release it.

Hope this helps you pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need manually release any object created by convenience constructors , see more about
[**convenience constructors**](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/07/27/cocoa.html?page=3)